# Calculating L-smoothness constant for logistic regression.

Tags: lipschitz-functions, hessian-matrix, logistic-regression

I am trying to find the $L$-smoothness constant of the following function (logistic regression cost function) in order to run gradient descent with an appropriate stepsize.

The function is given as $f(x)=-\frac{1}{m} \sum_{i=1}^m\left(y_i \log \left(s\left(a_i^{\top} x\right)\right)+\left(1-y_i\right) \log \left(1-s\left(a_i^{\top} x\right)\right)\right)+\frac{\gamma}{2}\|x\|^2$ where  $a_i \in \mathbb{R}^n, y_i \in\{0,1\}$,$s(z)=\frac{1}{1+\exp (-z)}$  is the sigmoid function.

The gradient is given as
$\nabla f(x)=\frac{1}{m} \sum_{i=1}^m a_i\left(s\left(a_i^{\top} x\right)-y_i\right)+\gamma x $.

My ideas was that the smoothness constant $L$ has to be bigger than all the eigenvalues of the hermitian of the given function, this follows from the fact that if $f$ is $L$-smooth, $g(x)=\frac{L}{2} x^T x-f(x)$ is a convex function and therefore the hessian has to be positive semi-definite.
The second-order partial derivatives of $f$ are given as

$ \frac{\partial^2 }{\partial x_k \partial x_j}f(x)=\frac{1}{m} \sum_{i=1}^ms(a_i^{\top} x)\left(1-s(a_i^{\top} x)\right)[a_i]_k[a_i]_j+\gamma\delta_{ij} $

from the following github post (https://github.com/ymalitsky/adaptive_GD/blob/master/logistic_regression.ipynb) i know that $ L=\frac{1}{4} \lambda_{\max }\left(A^{\top} A\right)+\gamma$ , where  $\lambda_{\max }$ denotes the largest eigenvalue, which seems good since i figured out that $s(a_i^{\top} x)\left(1-s(a_i^{\top} x)\right)\leq \frac{1}{4}$ for all $x$.

But i am not able to fit everything together. I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my idea:

Given the Hessian matrix (follow your notation):
\begin{equation}
      \begin{aligned}
          \nabla^2 f(x) &= \frac{1}{m}\sum_{i=1}^{m}s(-y_i a_i^Tx)(1-s(-y_i a_i^Tx))a_ia_i^T + \gamma I_d.
      \end{aligned}
  \end{equation}

To show $f(x)$ is $L$-smooth, we apply Theorem 5.12 in [1][p. 114]: if $||\nabla^2 f(x)||_2\leq L$ for any $x\in\mathbb{R}^d$, then $f(x)$ is $L-$smooth. We then provide the value of $L$:
\begin{equation}
      \begin{aligned}
          ||\nabla^2 f(x)||_2 &\leq ||\frac{1}{m}\sum_{i=1}^{m}\frac{1}{4}a_ia_i^T + \gamma I_d||_2 & \text{by } s(t)(1-s(t)\leq \frac{1}{4} \,\forall t\in\mathbb{R} \\
          &\leq\frac{1}{4m}||A^TA||_2 + \gamma & \text{by triangle inequality}\\
          &\leq \frac{\lambda_{max}}{4m} + \gamma & \text{by }\frac{||A^TAx||^2_2}{||x||^2_2}\leq\lambda_{max}^2\\
          &\leq\frac{\lambda_{max}}{4}+\gamma.
      \end{aligned}
  \end{equation}
Therefore, $f(x)$ is $L$-smooth with $L=\frac{\lambda_{max}}{4}+\gamma$. $\blacksquare$

[1] Beck, A. (2017). First-order methods in optimization. Philadelphia, PA: Society for Industrial and Applied Mathematics.